# Our core products' names are changing - thinking about pros and cons of changing the names on existing Product2 records vs. creating new ones

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, product, cpq

We are in the process of changing the naming scheme of our product tiers. Within Salesforce CPQ and elsewhere we have quite a few automations and processes that look for specific product names and codes to determine the outcome of various business logic like pricing and bundle requirements.

I am trying to decide whether to simply change the Product Name values (and product codes?) on the existing product2 records, or to create new Product2 records with the new names (and eventually deactivate the old ones).

Has anyone here gone through a similar situation? What did you decide to do? What are some the consequences of this that I may not be anticipating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating new products and (eventually) deactivating the old ones is most likely the way to go. Keep in mind that when you change a record, you change the appearance of that record everywhere that you reference it. This is also why salesforce.com recommends that you deactivate a user and create a new one, instead of altering an old user record to a new person. Doubly so if this data might eventually appear on customer-facing media (emails, self-service portals, etc).

Simply changing the name has the possibility of screwing up all your reporting and historical data, possibly by someone other than yourself years down the road ("Huh. Look at these customers that were using XYZ back in 2014, but I thought XYZ didn't come out until 2017..."). Simply recycling records tends to be more problematic than you realize, which you usually *won't* realize until 9-12 months later (or longer).

However, since you're also integrating with other systems, you might need to test the behavior of those systems when the old, familiar products disappear and new ones take their place, or when a ton of new ones are introduced overnight. It might be cataclysmic (duplicate or corrupt data, etc), or it might be innocuous. There's no real way to tell without performing a test, preferably in a sandbox/test environment.

Finally, there's simply the case of figuring out the product. For example, if you do contracts or services, you probably need to maintain historical accuracy, so new products is the way to go; when they renew their contract, do the switch at that time. For products, the distinction is a little harder, but you probably still want to introduce them as new products. This makes it easier to tell that they bought an WXY and not a *bona fide* XYZ product, perhaps to suggest an upgrade to the latest version, etc.

While there are some legitimate cases to simply renaming products (or any type of record in general), great care should always be taken beforehand to minimize any unwanted side effects.

EDIT: One additional note here. Storage is not affected by the number of products you have in the system, so there's really no penalty from a database perspective of creating all new records instead of recycling current records. You won't fill up your capacity of product records, and you get to maintain historical data by using the Archive feature.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I was initially leaning strongly toward just recycling the existing records due to the overhead of testing all the downstream systems with new products. But all of what you described here seems pretty convincing, especially when you compare it with recycling user records.

Comment: @Dupe_jockey Also, I think I'll edit this in, but Product2 *does not use storage space*, just like users don't use storage space, so that's an added factor. Salesforce is clearly encouraging us to not overwrite existing products.